# How to make this detuned stab

Tags: sound, design, replication

On 3:40 and 3:44 you hear a detuned stab in the background. I have a waldorf blofeld and what I'm looking for is to make some stabs and / or chords with a really distinct sound like you hear the song. I was wondering what are some basics to get started. To me it sounds it got this character because of some sort of detune or maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take 2-4 saw oscillators and detune each by 2-4 cents - except the first one.
2. For the envelope, use a medium decay with slighty longer release.
3. Add a ~2.5 s plate reverb
4. Locate the root (e.g. the tune is in C) play C# on top of "the rhythm section".